# Can I use getattr with method chaining in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I'm looking to capture the rolling mean and rolling standard deviation of a Series in two separate variables. I was hoping to reduce the code to a single function and pass the attribute I need (mean() or std()) dynamically, but I can't get it to work with the rolling attribute.

I've getattr by itself, I've tried the rgetattr in the basic_utils package, and I've tried the pipe method. All of them return errors.

Ideally, I'd be using something like this:

```
    func = getattr(pandas.DataFrame, type)

    return series.rolling(period).func()
```

Calling that particular function returns an error:
`AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'func'`

If I try something like this

```
    func = getattr(pandas.DataFrame, type)

    return func(series.rolling(period))
```

I get 
`AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute '_stat_axis_number'`

I can solve the problem by just using separate functions, but the repeats bother me. Thanks in advance for help anyone can provide.

Comment: Your variable `func` has no relationship to the attribute access `.func`

Comment: Ok, why are you using `getattr` on the `pd.DataFrame` class and then applying it to a `Rolling` object? You shouldn't expect that to work. Have you tried `getattr(series.rolling(period), type)()`?

Comment: First off, what are you even trying to do?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that did the trick, thank you. I was operating off of the assumption that because std() is a separate function from rolling() that it had to be called independently with getattr, rather than as a part of the method chain. If you post your suggestion as the answer I'll mark it as the answer.